# Effect of S-gate on one qubit of a combined(maybe entangled) state of 3 qubits

Tags: quantum-computing, q#, qubit

Suppose I have a register(qs) of 3 qubits (first 2 being used solely for control, the last one is the input) . The first two control qubits are in the `|+>` state and the state of the 3rd input is unknown. Let it be `a|0> + b|1>`.

Now I apply CCNOT(qs[0],qs[1],qs[2]) so their combined state becomes `0.5(a,b,a,b,a,b,b,a)` in Transposed matrix form [Please correct if I'm wrong here] . Now I apply S-gate to the 3rd qubit which transforms `|1> -> i|1>` .

I am unable to guess the state of the combined state of 'qs' now.

What I thought:

1. One logic is to multiply every state by 'i' if it has the form`|XY1>` so the combined state becomes `0.5(a,ib,a,ib,a,ib,b,ia) [Transposed]`
2. Another logic is to find tensor product of `(I x I x S)` since I'm not changing the first 2 qubits. Performing this yields a different result which is `0.5(a,b,a,b,ia,ib,ib,ia) [Transposed]` [Again, correct me if I'm wrong].

Which is the correct output after passing through S-gate (if any) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two qubits can't start in |+> state, since |+> is a single-qubit state. I assume that the starting state of the first two qubits in the register is `0.5 (|00> + |01> + |10> + |11>)`.

Both approaches are correct, because they are different ways to represent the same transformation. The first answer `0.5(a,ib,a,ib,a,ib,b,ia) [Transposed]` is correct. Your second answer `0.5(a,b,a,b,ia,ib,ib,ia) [Transposed]` seems to be obtained by multiplying by `S x I x I`, i.e., applying `S` gate on the first qubit instead of the third one.

The tensor product `I x I x S` can be calculated as tensor product of `I x I` (which is just a 4x4 identity matrix) and `S`. The result is an 8x8 matrix which consists of 16 copies of `S` matrix, multiplied by corresponding elements of `I x I`:

```
1 0 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 0 0
0 i | 0 0 | 0 0 | 0 0
- -   - -   - -   - -
0 0 | 1 0 | 0 0 | 0 0
0 0 | 0 i | 0 0 | 0 0
- -   - -   - -   - -
0 0 | 0 0 | 1 0 | 0 0
0 0 | 0 0 | 0 i | 0 0
- -   - -   - -   - -
0 0 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 1 0
0 0 | 0 0 | 0 0 | 0 i
```

If you multiply the state of the qubits by this matrix, you'll get the same answer as in the first approach.